# Rendered if condition in VF Page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have an IF condition in my outputtext field. I want to display 0.00 if the value is not exist into the field. Below is the condition that I am using to display the value

```
<apex:outputText  rendered="{!IF(CONTAINS(it.oppName, 'xxxxx'),true, false)}" value="{!ti.Name__c}"/>
```

May I know how to display 0.00 instead of empty when the value is not available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use formula in value of apex:outputText as well.

```
<apex:outputText  rendered="{!CONTAINS(it.oppName, 'xxxxx')}" value="{!IF(CONTAINS(it.oppName, 'xxxxx'),ti.Name__c, '0.00')}"/>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Always replace `IF(condition, true, false)` with just `condition`.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Your suggestion works for rendered but for value have to use IF condition there. Updated the answer.

Comment: Yep exactly. Not saying `IF` is always bad.

Comment: Hi I tried the above option, but its still coming as null only. That Name__c field is number field so I changed the condition to <apex:outputText  rendered="{!CONTAINS(it.oppName, 'xxxxx')}" value="{!IF(ti.Name__c != NULL,ti.Name__c, '0.00')}"/>... I think the issue is we are checking if name__c is null or not, but we should check oppName

Comment: @KSL You can use 'ISNULL(ti.Name__c)' instead of 'ti.Name__c != NULL', looks nicer and works better..

Comment: I am sorry if my questions is wrong. the Name__c is never going to be null. we need to check if it.oppName contains xxxxx or not. If it.oppName doesnot contain the xxxxx then we need to display the value as 0.00 otherwise ti.Name__c

Comment: You can change value="{!IF(ti.Name__c != '',ti.Name__c, '0.00')}" to value="{!IF(CONTAINS(it.oppName, 'xxxxx'),ti.Name__c, '0.00')}"

Comment: It worked.. We don't need rendered in that case.. Thanks :)